# Add Animated Gif to Clipboard in UWP

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

How can I go about adding an animated GIF to the clipboard from a universal windows 10 app so that it can be pasted in another app?

Answer (score 0):

it's possible.

You can read this article to copy a image from Windows Store app to the clipboard is still valid for UWP apps.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/clipboard-operations-in-windows-store-apps-using-C-Sharp/

Please mark this answer if it's useful for you! Thank you

Update:

I tried your scenario it seems gif images are not supported. there is not documentation about this issue

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't remain as an animated gif when doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the gif file to the [DataPackage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.aspx) as a file with [SetStorageItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205913.aspx) rather than as a bitmap with [SetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738426.aspx). The bitmap clipboard format is static bitmaps only. Many bitmap enabled targets will attach and interpret the file.

See the [Copy and Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/copy-and-paste) docs on MSDN.